# What does the phrase "woodsy home" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "woodsy home" in the following text:

*You can see that as with Sneaky Sasquatch **woodsy home**, how you experience the updated game is up to you. You can hang out at a cafe or diner.*

The phrase "woodsy home" may mean "a home that resembles woods" because in the game Sasquatch is a wild creature that steals items from nearby campsites. However, I am not sure about this.

Comment: In this context, I think "woodsy" means a home that you would find in the woods, like a quaint, rustic little cabin, smelling of pine trees, cozy, surrounded by trees.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the dictionary:

> **woodsy**
>   /ˈwʊdzi/
>   adjective: woodsy; comparative adjective: woodsier; superlative adjective: woodsiest
>   **relating to or characteristic of wood or woodland**.

It seems a common AmEng thing to make an adjective more friendly or diminutive by adding *-sy* to the end of it, for example "*cutesy*". You could just say something is cute, or in the woods, but "cutesy" and "woodsy" just sound more friendly and fun.